# How to run CreateObject() in VBA code with .exe generated in CodeBlocks IDE

Tags: vba, exe, command-prompt

I am trying to generate an .exe file an integrate it with my Excel VBA code.

I am using CodeBlocks IDE to generate the .exe, Excel2013 and CodeBlocks2013 versions on a 64-bit computer.

I created my CodeBlocks project (my_program1) in two ways i.e. "Console Application" and "Empty Project", and compiled the project successfully in both the cases.

When I run the .exe from command prompt, I am able to get desired results in both cases.

However, when I run the same commands by invoking the .exe from my VBA code, it shows no results i.e. blank.

I printed out the commands which my VBA code executes and found that they as same as the commands which i use in the command prompt (correct file paths etc.)

When I execute the command via command prompt i.e.
*D:\my_program1.exe list*, i get the names in my command prompt.

Following is part of my VBA code:

```
//list = command which my_program accepts and returns list of names
command_for_name = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\my_program1.exe list"
//here, message box shows D:\my_program1.exe list
MsgBox command_for_name  
//names returned by my_program1 to be seen in cell F7
Cells(7, "f").Value = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd.exe /S /C" & command_for_name).StdOut.ReadAll
```

However, Cell F7 is blank.

I even tried.

```
MsgBox CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd.exe /S /C" & command_for_name).StdOut.ReadAll
```

however, the message box is also blank.

What should I change to get the .exe to work with my VBA code?

**Thanks a lot in advance!**

Comment: Change to C#, Visual studio community and write a library that is com visible.  Lots of examples for you to look at.  You'll then be able to create an object in Excel VBA which exposes the functions you wish to use.  Probably a lot simpler than an extenal exe file.

Comment: No space after `/c`.

Comment: @user14797724 I added space after /c, however it still doesn't work

Comment: @freeflow I am not well-versed with C#. This question is to figure out why my .exe works from command prompt but not from Excel VBA code.

Comment: Now is the ideal time to learn.  C#, at the VBA level, is actually quite straightforward to use.

Comment: @freeflow Surely. "Lots of examples for you to look at. You'll then be able to create an object in Excel VBA which exposes the functions you wish to use." Can you share some links of tutorials which I can refer?

Comment: Your starter for 10  http://csharphelper.com/blog/2013/10/make-a-c-dll-and-use-it-from-excel-vba-code/  . It will be necessary for you to install Visual Studio COmminity 2019. Open a conversation if you need more guidance.

Comment: @freeflow Thanks a lot for the help. In-fact I already installed Sharpdevelop and executed a simple Hello World example. Will go through your link here.